# How to define height to an element in react native in android?

Tags: react-native

I'm currently developing an app to be used in an Android tablet, unfortunately I got comfortable and added too many features in web view before testing again on android and now they look quite different.
I have a few elements in a `flex-box view` with `flex-direction 'row'`, this is how they look on the browser and how they should look:
[image]

Then the same app on android looks like this:
[image]
You can see the two lines with inputs without proper height to fit the text, and a third line on the bottom already from another input.

This is the component code (I removed one input line to make it simpler):

```
<View>
  <Text style={styles.header}>
    {LanguageService(language).form.personalData}:
  </Text>
  <View style={styles.twoColumns}>
    <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
      <Text>
        {LanguageService(language).form.firstName}:
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('firstName')}
        value={formikProps.values.firstName}
        maxLength={20}
      />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
      <Text>
        {LanguageService(language).form.phone}:
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('phoneNumber')}
        value={formikProps.values.phoneNumber}
        keyboardType='phone-pad'
        maxLength={15}            
      />
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

And here is the style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  twoColumns: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',  
  },
  inputWrapper: {
    width: '48%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    margin: 10,
  },
  input: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
  },
  header: {
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 22,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this by removing the following line:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  twoColumns: {
    flex: 1,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the shape in the first image with this structure:

---

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.header}>
      {LanguageService(language).form.personalData}:
    </Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
    <View stlye={styles.leftContainer>
      <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
        <Text>
          {LanguageService(language).form.firstName}:
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('firstName')}
          value={formikProps.values.firstName}
          maxLength={20}
         />
      </View>
    </View>
    <View stlye={styles.rightContainer>
      <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
        <Text>
          {LanguageService(language).form.phone}:
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('phoneNumber')}
          value={formikProps.values.phoneNumber}
          keyboardType='phone-pad'
          maxLength={15}            
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

---

Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flex: 0.5
  },
  inputsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  leftContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1
  }
  inputWrapper: {
    width: '48%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    margin: 10,
  },
  input: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
  },
  header: {
    color: 'red',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 22,
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This solves the height issue, but the label + input is not spanning to ~50 % of the width.